# Spooling directory as source and hdfs as sink is stuck and not giving any error messages

Tags: hadoop, flume

i am trying to load some ".log" files from my local file system to hdfs using flume.I am using spooling directory as source and hdfs as sink.When i run agent using below command
**bin/flume-ng agent --conf /home/Flume/conf --conf-file /home/Flume/conf/test.conf --name agent**

when i execute above command its just listing below and nothing is happening(stuck).

> **Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /home/Flume/conf/flume-env.sh
>   Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/home/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
>   + exec /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/home/Flume/conf:/home/Flume/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*' -Djava.library.path=:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file /home/Flume/conf/test.conf --name agent**

please find below for contents of conf file

```
agent.sources = src1
agent.channels = chan1
agent.sinks = sink1
agent.sources.src1.type = spooldir
agent.sources.src1.spoolDir = /home//FlumeTesting/flume_sink
agent.sources.src1.basenameHeader = true
agent.sources.src1.deletePolicy = immediate
agent.sources.src1.fileHeader = true
agent.channels.chan1.type = memory
agent.channels.chan1.capacity = 10000
agent.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/flume_sink
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 1000
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 5000
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.idleTimeout = 60
agent.sinks.sink1.rollInterval = 500
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.filePrefix = %{basename}
agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileSuffix = .log
agent.sources.src1.channels = chan1
agent.sinks.sink1.channel = chan1
```

please correct me if there is any mistakes in this code or if i missed out anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your roll count / size values too high? In your path, are you sure those two slashes are correct? `/home//`... Is this a constant flow of files, or a one time push?

Comment: even i tried with roll count as 100 but still data not getting loaded.That // is a typo..please ignore that..

Comment: Okay, your didn't answer my last question. The spooling directory source only reads new files, not existing ones. Also, you're ingesting all files since you've not given a filename pattern

Comment: yes,i am ingesting all files in that folder.

Comment: Exactly. All **existing** files. Not **new** `.log` files

Comment: this issue is solved...some issue with hdfs.Thanks @cricket_007 for ur kind help..

Comment: Meaning what exactly? Can you provide an answer below of how you validated that HDFS was the problem?